# How to migrate Struts from 2.0 to 2.5?

Tags: struts2, upgrade, migrate

I am working on Struts 2.0 Project.

What are the steps and precautions needed to do while upgrading Struts from 2.0 to 2.5?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many things have changed since Struts 2.0 (that is 10 years old).

They're all described [in the **version notes** of each release](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Migration+Guide), that you should read.

The best shot you have, however, is to **bring your 2.0 project to a 2.3 one** (the latest version, that currently is 2.3.32).

The biggest things that you'll need to refactor (**from 2.0 to 2.3.32**) are:

- remove DMI (this will probably be the biggest).
- remove Dojo plugin and tags
- remove static method accesses
- change the filter
- change the `id` attribute to `var` attribute in tags
- change the `dtd`s of xml files (struts.xml, validation files etc)

Once you have a full working 2.3 project, you can follow the official [Struts **2.3 to 2.5** Migration Guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Struts+2.3+to+2.5+migration).

Remember that, while up to Struts 2.3 you were allowed to use **Java >= 6**, 
Struts 2.5 will run on **Java >= 7** only.

Good luck.

Comment: I have same issue and follow the migration Guide but having log4j issue i have used servlet 2.4 and struts 2.5.10.1 and jdk 8.0. but on server statu-up  getting logger error.

Comment: Servlet 2.4 ? You need Servlet 3.1 (also jsp 2.3.1, and change the web.xml dtd). And latest Struts releases use log4j2. It would be a lot easier to download (or create with Maven archetype) a brand new project, and copy the dependencies from that into your project

Comment: Thanks Andrea Ligios . But servlet 2.5  and jsp 2.0 working for me but dont know why ?. Just updated related jar with latest version and migrated successfully. i will have to check tag attributes related changes.

Comment: Servlet 2.4 -> J2EE 1.4; Servlet 2.5 -> Java EE 5; Servlet 3.0 -> Java EE 6; Servlet 3.1 -> Java EE 7. Also, this libraries are not in your WAR, they're on the application server shared libs. Tomcat 8.5, for example, has 3.1. It depends on the AS you are deploying your WAR to. I hope that, since you'll use Java 7+ now, you're not using an old Java 5 compliant AS ;)

Comment: "Struts 2.5 will run on Java >= 7 only" is this mandatory? Also, this link doesn't work for me.--> https://struts.apache.org/docs/struts-23-to-25-migration.html

Comment: @yeppe 1) Yes, for `2.5` it is mandatory, if you are using Java 6, continue using latest `2.3`. 2) Thanks, I've fixed both links. Now you can safely upvote :)

Comment: I still doubt that Java7 is necessary, Coz I am able to migrate to struts2.5 WITHOUT upgrading to java7 ...Hence, confused. Do you have anywhere in the migration notes specified that  mandates Java7 is mandatory for struts2.5 upgrade?? if yes, please let me know the link.

Comment: [The 2.5.x series of the Apache Struts framework has a minimum requirement of the following specification versions: Servlet API 2.4, JSP API 2.0, **and Java 7**](https://struts.apache.org/announce.html#a20170905). Hence you're using Java7 somewhere. Maybe in your IDE you've Java6 and in maven compiler plugin you've Java7, things like that. But feel free to post more, I'm curious