# How to migrate Struts from V2.0 to V2.5

Tags: struts2, migration

We are currently using Struts2.0, and planning to upgrade it to 2.5.X. Is there any migration process which helps me to directly upgrade to 2.5.X?, cause V2.0 is very old and lot of new things are implemented in later versions.

Some have suggested that don't migrate directly to 2.5.X as there are a lot of changes happened. However, first upgrade it to 2.3.X and then 2.5.X.

- [How to migrate Struts from 2.0 to 2.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42995276/how-to-migrate-struts-from-2-0-to-2-5)
- [What to modify when upgrading Struts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46728344/what-to-modify-when-upgrading-struts)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated links in my answer to your question mentioned above. However there's no direct link to the migration guide.

You can use [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Struts+2.3+to+2.5+migration) link if it could help you in the migration process.

Comment: Hi @Roman C, I'm in a project that owner dont want maven to artifats, then I have a lot of problem with dependecies on this, what can I do to identify dependencies because I'm using wildfly 20 module, and cant get deployment correctly, thank you

Comment: You can see what dependencies used by each artifact. Manually adding dependencies is difficult. You have a lot of problems if you don't know versions of the dependencies that are comfortable with your project work absolutely different.

Comment: Hi, I'm continue step by step drop exception, Your are reason in your words thank you by u comments

Comment: Hi, mr Roman. In my case my projects have been used Struts2.5 y tiles 2 and others plugins, it are inside of struts package like  json and ongl plugins. Well and all my configuration of dependencies was without maven or gradle, I try the post to tunning and my project work and deploy, thank you