# Failed to link org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/filter/StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter

Tags: eclipse, struts2

noclassdeffounderror StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter

I have a simple struts2 web dynamic project of eclipse, when I import all commons and assential jar in deployment assembly, my project run correttly but I create a module on wildfly 20 looking for share this module in other project, When I try run this the logging say StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter noclassdeffounderror  on module, I export all class on the jar an the class is right there on the file that was extract, I am not use maven in this project. please thank a lot for your next comment

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1) Use Maven (or equivalent). 2) You're likely missing a dependency, but without any actionable information, it's impossible to help.

Comment: @Dave Newton thanks, but owner project dont want maven..., I'm yet searching something can help me

Comment: Search for whatever library/libraries you’re missing. Even if you stood up a separate project just to determine and download the dependencies it’s faster than doing it by hand. Related: you don’t indicate what libraries you’re actually using, so there’s no way to compare against what libraries are required. Tangentially related: deliberately requiring projects to be harder than they need to be is an anti-pattern.

Comment: I'm work jdk 1.8 and web dynamic project inthis 3 images are all libs, firstable libs in my deployment assembly, the last two images are bouth module in wildfly 20 @DaveNewton

Comment: It's impossible to run into new version of Struts2 framework without learning how to upgrade from previous versions. It could be the problem and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58148759/573032) answer could help with the migration process.

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Please post text, not images of text.