# Error in updating Apache struts version in POM.xml after Building workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, struts

I am trying to update version in Apache struts from 2.3.35 to updated 2.5.22 in a project. I have changed version in pom.xml . However, I have cleaned, build and update Maven project . Still I am facing issues in POM.xml as artifact issues. Struts jar is not creating after update maven project and facing issues.

Please suggest me any other alternate solutions or steps to update struts version into updated one.

Comment: Please add the error output in whole not only excerpts etc. also more information about how you have called Maven.  Which Maven version are you using and JDK version etc.

Comment: I am using jdk 1.8

Comment: I just simply updated version with 2.5.22 in POM.xml and clean, build WS and run as maven build. after doing same, I start getting in pom.xml saying artifact path issue , new struts version is not creating in m2 folders. In other applications pom.xml same error I am getting.

Comment: Do I need to add more dependencies inside pom.xml / struts.xml for removal tag error in pom.xml

Comment: You can't update your application just changing a version of Struts artifact. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58148759/573032) answer if you have a specific problem or error and update your question.

Comment: There's no information here anyone can use to help; I don't see how it has three upvotes. You need to include actual details. "Facing issues" is not actionable. Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.